# Interview: is there any other place we can use volatile key word other than multi-threading?

Tags: java, volatile

I got asked this question during an interview. I don't give a case other than multi-threading.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html

Comment: Sounds like a trick question in someway

Comment: what was *their* answer?

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a variable `volatile` whether or not you're doing anything with multiple threads, but outside of multithreading it really is not useful and will make reads and writes of that variable slower with no appreciable gain.

Answer (score 0):

The only *specified* behaviors of `volatile` in the Java Language Specification (JLS) are in the Java Memory Model (JMM).  Since the JMM is all about whether and when one thread sees the results of a memory operation performed by another thread, then a simple "No" would be a valid answer to that question.  (In my opinion.)

Except ... that "can use" and "should use" mean different things in the English language.  So a pedant might point out that you "can" use `volatile` on field declarations where there is only one thread ever going to use the field.  You "can" do it.  It is permitted ... but it is pointless.

---

The other thing to note is that `volatile` causes the native code compiler to emit different code sequences.  These code sequences may cause your code to behave subtly differently in a context which the JLS / JMM would treat as out-of-scope.  For example, it might be relevant if you are (somehow) mapping object fields to memory-mapped hardware device registers, or the like.

However, this is all outside the scope of the Java language as specified in the JLS.  And definitely non-portable.  And irrelevant to normal Java programs / programmers.